# Specify range when reading Excel file via OLEDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a spreadsheet with > 255 columns and would like to read it in two chunks.

This is the connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""
```

The first SELECT returns 255 columns:

```
CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]"
```

The second SELECT throws an exception:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "IV1]"
```

Here I want all data starting in column IV (= column 256).

Exception:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E37): The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object ''3 Customers$'IV1'.
```

The sheet name is '3 Customers$'. I assume it has something to do with the apostrophes, but cannot figure out what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Try it with $ after the sheet name, e.g., `"SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "$]"`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278973

Comment: Oh wait, I just read the last line of your question. Have you already added the $ in the `SheetName` variable? Or does the sheet name actually end with a "$"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply add a named range in Excel and run this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [CA$MyNamedRange]"
```

If the sheet name ends with '$' you will have to change it, or handle it in code.  finally, make sure the Excel file is closed.  If it's open it can cause problems.